# Javascript default parameter with extra assignment

Tags: javascript

In javascript, we often see code like the following to set a default parameter when we don't care to ignore falsey values.

```
function SomeObject (param) {
    this.param = param || {};
}
```

Occasionally though, when reading code, I'll come across the following variation:

```
function SomeObject (param) {
    this.param = param = param || {};
}
```

Can someone explain to me the use case for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
function SomeObject (param) {
    this.param = param = param || {};
}
```

two separate assignments are made: one to the `param` local variable (the actual argument to the function) and one to a property of `this`, whatever that happens to be. Those two different assignment targets are **not** the same. (They'll get the same value of course, but they're two separate places to put values.)

In my experience, it's far more common to see a simple default established for the parameter itself:

```
function whatever(x) {
  x = x || {};
```

There's nothing wrong, however, with assigning to an object property when that makes sense.